# fetch data from firebase having a randomly generated key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the code that I am using to save value into firebase. It generates a random key for every value. (I want to save redundant data, so this method was necessary).

```
GenderOfNameHelperClass GONHC = new GenderOfNameHelperClass();
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("GenderOfName");
GONHC.setName(Name);
GONHC.setGender(Gender);
reference.push().setValue(GONHC);
```

This creates a structure as below:

```
db-ai-34201
-...GenderOfName
    -...M4oLyB1ADGLWGJG4EgR
        ...gender:"Female"
        ...name: "akira"
```

[image]

Now how can I fetch the data from this.
I want to fetch the gender, when name is searched from my android UI.

Answer (score 2):

This is the listener to the GenderOfName node to extract data under the random keys:

```
ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for(DataSnapshot snapShot:dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
       //these are the values of gender and name for every random key
       //in GenderOfName node

           String gender = snapShot.child("gender").getValue(String.class);
           String name = snapShot.child("name").getValue(String.class);              
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
};
```

Finally attach the listener to your reference of that node to start listening to it

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("GenderOfName");
reference.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

**UPDATE**

you can always use a query to filter results:

instead of this:

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("GenderOfName");
reference.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

try this,it will give you a specific snapshot based on the name you need:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("GenderOfName").orderByChild("name").equalTo(theNameYouWant);
query.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. It's recommended to explain what the solution you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam , I did not understand this code, will it fetch all the data from database? I want to fetch gender of a specific name that is mentioned on UI of application.

Comment: @DeepChhowala your question is about fetching data of random keys, not about a specific name.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam, no, my question was a bit different, please check the last line of my question above.   I tried an if loop inside of your code and it helped me, not sure if this is a permanent solution.